# How to call a function interactively

Tags: emacs, elisp, interactive

When I start up Emacs, I want it to fill the left half of my screen. I accomplish this using

```
;; set initial window size to the left half of the screen
(defun set-frame-pixel-size (frame width height)
  "Sets size of FRAME to WIDTH by HEIGHT, measured in pixels."
  (let ((pixels-per-char-width (/ (frame-pixel-width) (frame-width)))
        (pixels-per-char-height (/ (frame-pixel-height) (frame-height))))
    (set-frame-size frame
                    (floor (/ width pixels-per-char-width))
                    (floor (/ height pixels-per-char-height)))))

(defun use-left-half-screen ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((excess-width 32)
         (excess-height 48)
         (half-screen-width (- (/ (x-display-pixel-width) 2) excess-width))
         (screen-height (- (x-display-pixel-height) excess-height)))
    (set-frame-pixel-size (selected-frame) half-screen-width screen-height)))

(if window-system
    (use-left-half-screen))
```

And it works beautifully. However, I sometimes want to call that same command another time during the day. Hence, I do `M-x use-left-half-screen` but nothing happens.

That is, unless I run `M-: (set-frame-pixel-size (selected-frame) 1024 768)` (or something similar) first. If I do that, and I don't change the frame size using my mouse, then `use-left-half-screen` works. As soon as I change the frame size using the mouse or an OS shortcut, it ceases to work.

Do you have any ideas of how I can make `M-x use-left-half-screen` work?

Comment: I believe it depends also on your window manager and how / whether it respects the positioning etc requests from applications.

Comment: @tripleee `set-frame-pixel-size` works reliably, so that is not the case.

Comment: Well, it works for me (I executed the 2 defuns, ran use-left-half-screen interactively, it worked. I resized the frame with mouse, re-executed, it worked again)

Comment: Have you checked what `x-display-pixel-width` returns after you resize with mouse? What about putting `(set-frame-pixel-size (selected-frame) 1024 768)` at the beginning of `use-left-half-screen`? It seems unlikely that the problem has to do with `interactive`ness.

Comment: @Bahbar what OS/Emacs are you running?